# Executar comando mongoimport via c#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Preciso executar o comando mongoimport do mongoDB via código porem não da certo:

```
           `pro.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            //pro.UseShellExecute = false;
            pro.Arguments = @"/k cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\";
            Process proStart = new Process();
            proStart.StartInfo = pro;
            proStart.Start();
```

ai preciso executar o mongoimport que fica dentro da bin, porem não consigo.

Alguem pode dar um help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está apenas abrindo o cmd e navegando até a pasta bin do mongo

Um exemplo tirado do SOen

```
    public bool importCsv(string filepath,  string collectionName)
    {

    string result ="";
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongoimport.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = @" -d test -c " + collectionName + " --type csv --file " + filepath + " --headerline";
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
        proc.Start();
        result += "ddd";
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    if (!result.Equals(""))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Observer que o filename é o próprio `mongoimport`

```
 startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongoimport.exe";
```

Fonte | [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30666275/4200639)

Comment: Obrigado, porem ja tentei dessa forma e tambem não funciona, porem não estora erro então fica dificil de saber o que é, mais chamei direito o executavel do mongoimport e passei como argumento o comando e mesmo assim nao funciona :/

Comment: Desculpa, o código está errado vou fazer a correção

Comment: Agora sim, eu peguei o código do SOen  e adquei ao seu caso e esqueci de por o executavel. Tenta desta forma e verifica se resolve

Comment: Tem que passar o nome do executável `mongoimport.exe`

Comment: Fiz dessa forma mesmo passando o mongoimport.exe no filename e mesmo assim não funciona!

Comment: O pior é que nao consigo reproduzir algum erro que possa estar ocorrendo

Comment: Se você chamar direto pelo cmd vai?

Comment: Sim,pelo cmd: vou até a pasa bin e nela chamo o mongoimport -d test -c ... e funciona normal

Comment: Testa este código no c#  `Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongoimport.exe", @" -d test -c " + collectionName + " --type csv --file " + filepath + " --headerline");`