# Como localizar objetos wrapped no banco de dados

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Tenho um banco de dados com diversos objetos **wrapped**, e **preciso de uma forma fazer uma busca e localizar** todos os objetos que estão criptografados, ou seja, com a **wrap**, para posteriormente fazer um tratamento.

**O que são objetos wrapped:**

> "...Podemos e devemos proteger o nosso código no banco de dados
>   Oracle."
>
> "...Esta proteção pode ser feita no nosso código, isso é
>   chamado de **wrap**. Dessa forma criptografamos o nosso código, tornando
>   ele ilegível para outra pessoa. Claro que a recuperação de um código com wrap não é impossível, mas com certeza dificulta muito esse processo."
>   <sub>Fonte: [wrap-utility-criptografando-codigo](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/articles/sql/wrap-utility-criptografando-codigo-3305170-ptb.html)</sub>

Objeto sem wrap:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION teste RETURN  NUMBER IS
BEGIN
RETURN 1;
END teste;
/
```

Objeto wrapped:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION teste wrapped 
a000000
1
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
8
3d 71
m9n4KQ8rT+C9b7lU4HcO3pDzsUMwg8eZgcfLCNL+XhahYtGhXOfAsr2ym16lmYEywLIJpXSL
wMAy/tKGCamhBKPHvpK+FkZTOQdTo4KmpqsCL3g=

/
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028977/search-for-wrapped-packages-procedures-in-oracle-sql

Comment: TOPP @Motta, cria uma resposta com a referencia que eu marco como resolvida :D

Comment: Não permitem respostas só de links , deixa quieto.

Comment: Se quiser pode fazer algo assim: [1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202495/executar-comando-mongoimport-via-c/202499#202499) ou assim [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71544/qt-opencv-no-mac-os-10-10-3-com-error-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x8/71609#71609) com algum contexto e colocando o código do SOEN na resposta aqui, mas tu que sabe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já publicado

```
select type, owner, name
from all_source
where line = 1
  and instr(text, 'wrapped') > 1;
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028977/search-for-wrapped-packages-procedures-in-oracle-sql)